# 2d array, using calloc in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, calloc

I'm trying to create a 2D array of chars to storage lines of chars. For Example:

```
lines[0]="Hello";
lines[1]="Your Back";
lines[2]="Bye";
```

Since lines has to be dynamically cause i don't know how many lines i need at first. Here is the code i have:

```
int i;
char **lines= (char**) calloc(size, sizeof(char*));

for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
lines[i] = (char*) calloc(200, sizeof(char));
}

for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
free(lines[i]);
}

free(lines);
```

I know that each line can't go over 200 chars. I keep getting errors like "error C2059: syntax error : 'for'" and such. Any ideas of what i did wrong?

Comment: Do you have that code in a function?

Comment: You need to post the exact errors that you are getting.

Comment: Explicit casts not required in C.

Comment: Here are some of the errors.

syntax error : 'for'
syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

.in total there is 25 errors. 

No the code is not in a function.

Comment: I guess size is defined and initialized somewhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No the code is not in a function.

You can't just put arbitrary statements outside of functions in C and C++. What you can do though is use a function to initialize the variable:

```
char** init_lines() {
    char** ln = /* ... */;
    // your allocations etc. here
    return ln;
}

char** lines = init_lines();
```

Comment: C and C++ simply work that way, you can only have declarations and definitions outside of functions. I recommend reading a good introductory book, look e.g. here for C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list ... and here for C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question with C++ -- why not use a `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` for this?

Looking at the compiler error, it looks like you're missing a semicolon before one of your for loops -- the code you posted seems to work perfectly fine here.

Comment: At first i thought thats what i did, but if i get rid of the code the rest of program runs fine.

Comment: @BigBirdy: That just means adding the for causes the semicolon missing to cause a problem parsing the code. Check again -- the code you posted compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, it's a waste of time doing that first `calloc` since you immediately initialise them with the first `for` loop.

Having said that, there's nothing at all wrong with the code you've shown.

Therefore, either your error lies elsewhere or that's not the code you've posted. I suggest you post the exact error message along with a cut-and-pasted copy of the offending line and ten lines either side of it for context. That will make our lives a lot easier in helping you out.

---

The errors:

```
syntax error : 'for' syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
syntax error : missing ';' before '<' missing type specifier - int assumed
```

as shown in one of your comments is usually caused by unbalanced parentheses. Check all your `(` and `)` characters to ensure they're equal in number, and in the right place. It's probably because you're missing a `)` in the statement before the `for` but that's just an educated guess since the code you posted does not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm opinion is different. May be useful. char pointer or char double is implicitly define during compilation. Hence it is not need to define explicitly and by doing so it show syntax error. Try char pointer without initializing by calloc and if you don't want garbage value initialize with NULL. It act like using calloc, you find nothing different.